# how to disable all previous dates in "to date" of the selected "from-date"

Tags: jquery, html, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a date range with 2 fields,

```
<input type='text' id='from-date' name='from-date'>
<input type='text' id='end-date' name='end-date'>
```

1. I need to disable all previous dates in from-date before current date( this is done and working fine).
2. After selecting from-date, we need to disable all the previous date in to-date from from-date( facing issues on this).

I have tried the following datepicker jquery code, but im missing something, please correct me.

```
$( "#start-date" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})
    .on("input change", function (e) {
        $( "#end-date" ).datepicker({ minDate:  e.target.value, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
```

**Update : For those who are still trying, here is the fix**

*Im using below code to satisfy the above condition*

```
$("#start-date").datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(obj, event){
        var from_date = $("#start-date").datepicker("getDate");
        $("#end-date").datepicker("option","minDate",from_date);
    }
});
$("#end-date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix for the above question:

```
$("#start-date").datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(obj, event){
        var from_date = $("#start-date").datepicker("getDate");
        $("#end-date").datepicker("option","minDate",from_date);
    }
});
$("#end-date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

Instead of giving direct date format for minDate, we need to use this function to get the selected from-date: `$("#start-date").datepicker("getDate");`